# Implementing MATLAB find in Fortran

Tags: matlab

I am translating MATLAB code into FORTRAN.

```
[m,label] = min(result.data.d')
```

result.data.d dimensions are(1484,8).So with transpose,program is minimizing rows or columns?

```
        for i = 1:c
       index=find(label == i);
       dat{i}=data.X(index,:);
       meret(i)= size(dat{i},1);
       end
```

From Mathworks.com:

```
k = find(X) returns a vector containing the linear indices of each nonzero element in array X
```

I do not understand why index was used here.

Comment: It is how find works. It finds all the non-zero elements in a vector and return the index where it appear in the vector you use find on. There is a few more features, so I recommend that you check the documentation before you start (`doc find`).

Comment: index is being used as a row index into X.